# PHP Converting GitHub Markdown Image URLs to Published Page URLs

Tags: php, image, preg-replace, markdown

I need to convert via PHP all Markdown URLs in a chunk of text like:

`https://github.com/username/myrepo/blob/master/images/subdir/voyage-dans-la-lune.jpg`

to the URLs when published via GH pages, e.g.

`https://username.github.com/myrepo/images/subdir/voyage-dans-la-lune.jpg`

My preg_replace pattern is failing:

`$replace = preg_replace('\'https://github.com/([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+)/blob/master/images\'',  'https://\\1.github.io/\\2/images', $content, -1, $rcount);`

Am hoping it's something trivial I am overlooking.

Comment: Can you please write clearly what is your input string and expected output?

Comment: This code works well (despite of the useless backslashes and the stupid choice for the delimiter). What is the problem?

Comment: See: https://eval.in/798638

Comment: Thanks for the cleaner pattern; my error was a mistake in what I was doing with the return value of the function. It's working now